# Alexa: Struggling to reference list/item under intent

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-slot

I'm starting out and trying to develop some skills for Alexa, but I seem to hit the same stumbling block every time, and no matter how much I try I'm not able to overcome it. I've tried using the various templates around and then modifying them to meet my own needs, but even this doesn't seem to work.

For example : Here is the sample for selecting your favourite colour. This works absolutely fine on it's own. But if I try to reference my own intent 'CharacterIntent', I cannot store the Intent, it's name, the slot, or the the value at all.

When I test a command, I can see the Lambda command references the correct intent, slot name and item. If I was to run an if statement looking for 'CharacterIntent' it will never find it.

I've worked from at least 5 different examples. Started ground up and gone through them line by line to understand what I'm doing wrong, but I can't crack it. I've deleted projects and re-started a ton of times. I'm getting frustrated with it now as this shouldn't be this complicated, but I don't know what I am missing.

I have deleted the project I had - and will start again. But I'm hoping someone can offer some insight for me before I lose all my hair.

Thanks

Anthony

```
function setColorInSession(intent, session, callback) {
const cardTitle = intent.name;
const favoriteColorSlot = intent.slots.Color;
let repromptText = '';
let sessionAttributes = {};
const shouldEndSession = false;
let speechOutput = '';

if (favoriteColorSlot) {
    const favoriteColor = favoriteColorSlot.value;
    sessionAttributes = createFavoriteColorAttributes(favoriteColor);
    speechOutput = `I now know your favorite color is ${favoriteColor}. You can ask me ` +
        "your favorite color by saying, what's my favorite color?";
    repromptText = "Yo
    u can ask me your favorite color by saying, what's my favorite color?";
} else {
    speechOutput = "I'm not sure what your favorite color is. Please try again.";
    repromptText = "I'm not sure what your favorite color is. You can tell me your " +
        'favorite color by saying, my favorite color is red';
}

callback(sessionAttributes,
     buildSpeechletResponse(cardTitle, speechOutput, repromptText, shouldEndSession));
```

}

Comment: If I understand your question correctly -- the above code sample works stand-alone, but when combined with some other code to repeat the user's favorite color via session attribute, it fails to do so.  Is that correct?  If so, can you include that other code that uses your session attributes, and maybe some sample request/response bodies too?

Comment: Hi, sorry - No. My issue was whenever I was trying to reference something in a list - I could not do it. Even when I was just slightly modifying the code of an already working reference (Such as the colours above). The good news is I managed to crack it - and I can now reference the list value.

I do have a follow on question though. How do I get the index of a list value? const characterSlot = intent.slots.Characters & const selectedCharacter = characterSlot.value; gives me the text of the selected item, but I want to know how to get the index number (0,1,2,3) etc.